# How to change the transition animation from bottom to top in navigation controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, segue

I am new to iOS. I am trying to change the transition animation in navigation controller to load a new UIView controller from bottom to top, using Segue. I believe it will not be too hard to implement but may be I am not able to understand it.

I could not find any solution in other posts.

Here's the code I've been trying:-

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"alarmSegue"]) {
    tab2ViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    UIView *destView = destViewController.view;
    destViewController.selectionName = @"alarms";

    [sender setEnabled:NO];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         [destView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -1000)];
                         //[destView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 440, 400, 45)];
                         //destView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [sender setEnabled:YES];
                     }];
    [UIView commitAnimations];


     }
 }
```

I just want to implement a SIMPLE transition from bottom to top, using Segue. I want to set some properties of destination controller as well.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the code between `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];` and `[UIView commitAnimations];` (including those two lines as well) with the following:

```
CGAffineTransform baseTransform = destView.transform; //1
destView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(baseT,0,destView.bounds.size.height); //2

[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 animations:^{ 
    destView.transform = baseTransform; //3
}];
```

1. Make a reference of the original transform.
2. Push our view down without an animation so we can animate it back up
3. Set the original transform back to the view. This time, it'll animate

You can further add the delay, options and completion parameters to that UIView Animation method. Xcode will probably help you with the autocompletes on those.

Answer (score 2):

Well you are nearly there.

You need to change two things mainly:

1 Change the initial position of the view. You want the view to appear from bottom to top, so initially your view should be at the bottom. This piece of code should be written before the animation.

> [destView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -1000)];

2 Then you need to slide from bottom to the original position , hence inside the animation block:

> ```
>  [destView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)];
> ```

One more suggestion, I guess you are using a newer version of iOS(above iOS4) instead of using animation blocks use UIView's animation method

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

For further info, refer [description](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3adelay%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a).

**EDIT :**
According to your edit on question, you are looking to change the transition animation for NavigationController in the app using storyboard. For that you could use Custom Segue. You will have to create a custom segue, a class that subclasses UIStorySegue and override its `perform` method like this:

```
-(void)perform {
    //UIViewAnimationOptions options;
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];

    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.9f;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom

    [destinationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
    [sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

You have to change the segue class to this custom segue in storyboard as well, to make it function.

Comment: yes I tried [destView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)]; and then the first line 2nd parameter being -1500. It works but while our animation, default animation from right to left is visible. Can we stop that?

Comment: After animating, segue is not performed, and so the properties which are required at destination controller is not received. How can I perform segue with animation?

Comment: are you using a navigation controller? If yes, then you are asking a wrong question. You should then look for, how to change the transition animation in navigation controller. the solution I pasted would be more useful in case you are adding the view as a subview on another view

Comment: oh is it! Let me change the question then. And as you have got the idea what I have been trying to achieve, can you help me with that then?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `transition effects`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"alarmSegue"]) {


        CATransition transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.duration = 0.5;
        transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
        transition.subtype = direction;
        [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];

        tab2ViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        UIView *destView = destViewController.view;
        destViewController.selectionName = @"alarms";

        [sender setEnabled:NO];

         }
     }
```

Comment: I'm trying. Could you please tell me what is "direction" in the transition.subtype ?

Comment: Put it like as string `@"left"` or `@"top"`

Comment: Thanks! I got it. But what I'm trying is to open a new view which will animate from bottom to top, a simple animation like the default (which is right to left).

Comment: @NirajBurde does it not opening the new view in similar manner

Comment: it animated the transition of current view when going off the screen

Comment: @ HimanshuJoshi I want the new view to load from bottom of the screen to the top.